# How to Solve below problem set in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table whose structure is Trn_Id , Trn_Start_Date ,Division_Code,Station_Code, Actual_Date_Time and I have to find total train delay in minutes for a particular Trn_Id & Trn_Start_Date division wise .

e.g.
Here in the example given Delay for Trn_Id 1001 & Tr_start_Date 20 Aug in Division XYZ is 40 min ,in Division PAL it is 70 minutes which adds up to 110 minutes but if we look at the total train delay it is 03:30 AM - 01:10 AM = 140 minutes .
Now the missing point is when division changes from XYZ to PAL ,so that transition point has to be taken into consideration which will give additional minutes ( 02:20-01:50 = 30 minutes ) ,
so overall train delay is 110+30 =140  minutes

But I don't know in which division's account should I give this delay , XYZ or PAL ? Even if we can randomly give this to any division then how to calculate the total train delay division wise .
Please guide .

[image]

Comment: And how do you know what the delay is?

Comment: I think some data is missing from your example. There is no time portion in trn_start_date so you can't see what the planned start time is. Note that screenshots for representing data are a challenge for whoever wants to responds.The create table script (text not screenshot) and the dml for a couple of sample rows would be very helpful. That way we can quickly reproduce your question in our local environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the duration for each division, you can use `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select division_code, sum(next_adt - actual_date_time)
from (select t.*,
             lead(actual_date_time) over (partition by trn_id, trn_start_date order by actual_date_time) as next_adt
      from t
     ) t
group by division_code;
```

This should work regardless of how many divisions are in the data.